# Apache deny development sites, but one url

Tags: apache

My devsite is running with other production sites. I need to deny the dev sites, but allow one url of dev sites to be accessible.

```
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My Development Site"
  AuthUserFile /path_to/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user

  # Need to deny devsite, and working!
  SetEnvIf Host .*\.dev\.site\.com$ DEV_SITE

  # But allow x.dev.site.com/xml/, I think the idea is to unset DEV_SITE, 
  # but not working!
  SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/xml/ !DEV_SITE 

  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from env=DEV_SITE

  Satisfy any
```

Comment: "My devsite is running with other production sites" ... that sounds scary..

Comment: @Ben Yes, they are running on the same server. It costs money to run on separate server. Perhaps we can in the future.